# Eclipse/MinGW issue with C++ User-defined Literals

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I've been programming in C++11 using MinGW as the compiler and Eclipse as the IDE for a little while now, and it's generally been without fail. However there is one thing that has caused me issues for a little while, and so I figure I'll give it a shot asking here.

Every time I attempt to define a user-defined literal, Eclipse underlines it in yellow with the error message "`Syntax Error`" -- and will also underline any utilization of said literal. Despite this, it compiles properly.

**My attempts at a solution:**

1. At first glance it just appears like it needs the index rebuilt, or that it possibly doesn't recognize that it's compiling in c++11 -- however this is not the case. Not only do I have the compiler flag `-std=c++11`, but I've also set the built-in compiler settings in Eclipse to be set to C++11. Plus, it compiles all other C++11 expressions without fail, it seems to only be an issue with the literals
2. My second thought was that perhaps MinGW wasn't implementing a sufficient version of G++ to handle user-defined literals. However, running `g++ --version` shows that I'm running version 4.8.1, and they were added somewhere back in 4.7
3. My last thoughts were that maybe the CDT eclipse plugin was out of date or something, but there doesn't appear to be any newer versions available

So basically, I'm stumped.

An example of something that compiles fine but is underlined in the editor is:

```
constexpr float operator"" _deg ( float rad ){
    return rad * 180 / 3.1415926;
}
```

This isn't a huge issue because it compiles, but I hate seeing false-errors/warnings.

For reference, my specifications are:

```
Eclipse Version  : Kepler Service Release 2
CDT Version      : 8.5.0.201409172108
MinGW G++ Version: 4.8.1
```

Judging by the fact that I haven't seen any other questions similar to mine, I would assume it's an issue on my end -- so I'm hoping someone here has a suggestion for how to fix this.

Comment: ide is not yet up-to-date with new c++ features?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering, but it just seems strange that we're 2014 and nobody else (so far as I can tell) has had an issue with it. I've seen plenty of Visual Studio questions about it, but I can't find any on MinGW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable [CDT does to recognize C++11 features](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features). If you did that it's likely a bug in the CDT scanner and you should [try to report a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/)